# Xcode 7 XCTest app memory monitor

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode7, xctest

I created bunch of XCode7 UI tests that I run for every developer build, I wonder if I can track application memory usage from point when I start tests until all my tests finished so it could be analyzed later?

I start my tests by command-line:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme "AppSchema" -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s Plus,OS=9.3'
```